# isotope reLayout with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-isotope

I have almost 10 different AJAX call at document load. I've tried `insert()` and `reLayout()` functions of `Isotope` when `AJAX` is succeeded, but i couldn't get it work. I opened `jsFiddle` but `AJAX` not working because its not reachable from the outside. Although you can see the AJAX call and if you can tell me to what to do in this case I'd be so happy.

This is my repeating div and im loading content inside of the `#divMecraSatisDagilimi`:

```
    <div class="rowPanel2 blue">
        <div class="rowCaption2">
            Mecra Satış Dağılımı
        </div>
    <div id="divMecraSatisDagilimi">    
    </div>
</div>
```

but I can't find a way to attach this `div` to the `Isotope`.

Here's the jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nEzdQ/7/).

Comment: Not 100% sure if I understand your problem, but you realize that `$("#divAgentSiparisDagilimi").html(AgentSiparisDagilimi);` overwrites content every time the `success()` is invoked..?

Comment: Yes. That's where my problem begins. I want `Isotope` to  `reLayout() `every time i call that `AJAX`

Comment: I suggest you clarify more properly what you behaviour you want, cuz I dont think I get it.

Comment: Okay, i've updated my jsFiddle you can look in there if you want. jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nEzdQ/8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is isotope initialized? It needs to be initialized before you can run any action on the container

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.rowPanel'
});
```

Once this is done and since you are only editing the inside of your items as far as I can understand, you don't need to call the `insert` function, which is used to insert new items, you should use indeed the `reLayout` function inside of your ajax calls.

For example

```
$container =  $(".wallContent");

$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.rowPanel'
});

$.get("/service1", function(res){
   // Updating the content one of the rowPanel item
   $(".rowPanel:eq(0)").html(res);
   $container.isotope('reLayout');
});

$.get("/service2", function(res){
   // Updating the content another of the rowPanel item
   $(".rowPanel:eq(1)").html(res);
   $container.isotope('reLayout');
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i was initializing isotope but it seems to my problem was, i wasn't giving any width to the container element neither its `itemSelector` when i give default width to `.wallContent` and `.rowPanel` it worked.  Thanks for your advice, it helped me to think differently.